# Array: index -7 out of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get error:

```
index -7 out of array
```

What is wrong with my array? I can't store them too many digits, or what?

**UPDATED**

PS - (From json I get only ids)

```
answers_from_json = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params[:answers_from_json])

answers_from_json.each_with_index do |item, i|

   posts     = Post.find(:all, :conditions => ["id=?",item.to_i])


       sheet[header_y_offset-1,0]           = 'Name'   

   posts.each_with_index do |post,i|
    sheet[1+i,0]  = post.name
   end 
 end
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you posted the array.

Comment: My guess is that you wrote some code that does something that isn't what you meant. But I can't tell without seeing it.

Comment: Your question is like: "I have an error, do you know the solution?". More info plz!

Comment: You are reading a value from an array, thats not there - expecting an array to have more elements in it than it actually does (presumably 6 ;).

Comment: So, were you able to find the error?

Answer (score 1):

You are reading a value from an array, thats not there - expecting an array to have more elements in it than it actually does. Take another look at your `sheet` array, it may not have the `i+1` items in it.

EDIT : Keep in mind that with 0-based index, the last index of an array of length 7 is 6 ;)

Just print out it's length and the index you are trying to access.Then you might see the issue:

```
   posts.each_with_index do |post,i|
     p "length of the post: " + post.size
     p "trying to access element nr. : " + (i + 1)
     sheet[1+i,0]  = post.name
   end
```

If the error is not raised here, then it might be the `sheet[header_y_offset-1,0]`statement or a similar statement, where the error actually happens - you get the picture I hope. The optimal way would be to debug - but as I don't know ruby beyond thr basics -  I can only advise on how to print-debug - it should be enough.

Comment: this is not the problem here - definitely much much more then 7 - the problem is that the actual array you have is smaller then 7. As I said, just print it out and you might see

Comment: oh, ok.. I printed, and I have 133 elements

Comment: Edited the answer with alternative

Comment: in which line does the error occur? usually this is printed with the error message.